# Regex: Select Four Digit Number that doesn't start with two zeroes or end with two zeroes

Tags: regex

I'm new to Regex and I've been trying to do this without any luck. What am I doing wrong?

```
/^([^0]{2}[^0]{2})$/gm
```

It only selects the first one.

```
valid:
1234 <--
0101
1001

invalid
1200
0012
0000
2131sdf
sdf2343
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression which uses [Negative Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

```
^(?!00|.*00$)\d{4}$
```

Explanation:

```
^        # the beginning of the string
(?!      # look ahead to see if there is not:
  00     #   '00'
 |       #  OR
  .*     #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
  00     #   '00'
  $      #   before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)        # end of look-ahead
\d{4}    # digits (0-9) (4 times)
$        # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uM9vD6/1)

Comment: I'm a fan of this alternative method (kind of bummed I wrote `0{2}` after seeing `00`.....).

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

```
/^(?!0{2})[0-9]{4}(?<!0{2})$/gm
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/zO0lN0/1)

---

This uses a negative lookahead `(?!...)` and a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` to assert that there are not two `0`s (`0{2}`) after the start of the string (`^`) and before the end of the string (`$`). Lookarounds are zero-length assertions, meaning they do not match any characters (just like `^` and `$`). So in between these assertions, we still need to match 4 digits (`[0-9]{4}`).

Comment: Thanks Sam, but there seems to be some issue around the `(?<!0{2})`. I can't make it work.

Comment: Ahh, didn't even think of that. Next time you should tag your `regex` question with the language you plan to use it in. Each engine is implemented differently..for instance, JS cannot process negative lookbehinds (`(?<!...)`).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
/^(?!0{2})[0-9]{4}(?<!0{2})$/gm
```

This uses a negative lookahead (`?!...`) and a negative lookbehind (`?<!...`) to assert that there are not two 0s (`0{2}`) after the start of the string (^) and before the end of the string (`$`).

Lookarounds are zero-length assertions, meaning they do not match any characters (just like `^` and `$`). So in between these assertions, we still need to match 4 digits (`[0-9]{4}`).

Answer (score 0):

One more pattern:

```
^(?:(?!00)\d\d){2}$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/35)